# undo redirect http to https in nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx

I had to redirect http to https for `subdomain.domain.com` so I did `rewrite ^(.*) https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;` in `nginx.conf`. The `permanent` parameter is made client browser to always redirect to `https`. Now what I wanted is to remove `https` redirect. so `subdomain.domain.com` will redirect to `http://subdomain.domain.com`. but the client browser is set to always redirect to https and they can't visit `http://subdomain.domain.com` since it is redirect to `https://subdomain.domain.com`. how to resolve this problem?

Comment: All that `permanent` does is decide if a 301 or 302 response is sent. Most browsers will remove that when the cache expires.

Comment: @Basic but client open the url in chrome's incognito window, still it is redirect to https

Comment: If I ask client to clear cache content then will it work?

Comment: don't guess, try it. Recreate the problem and test it on one of your own servers. It _should_ work but there are many more factors which it is your responsibility to test before telling the client you've fixed the issue. See [here](http://getluky.net/2010/12/14/301-redirects-cannot-be-undon/) for more info